# Android: Geofencing is working fine when its in foreground but not working in background

Tags: java, android, google-api-client, android-geofence, location-services

I am a novice in Android development. I tried to develop an Android app which will show a Google Map with a fixed Geofence Area and the current location of the concerned person. Whenever he / she leaves or enters that particular geofence region a notification will be shown. After searching various forums and stackoverflow for ideas I somehow manged to develop the application. But I am now facing the problem that it shows the notfication about the Entry / exit of Geofence area only when the app is open. If it is minimized and swiped out it doesn't run in background. I used GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService for geofence transition changes. I think that I had done some silly mistake so it's not working in background. So please help me out from this problem.

Here's the full code. Any ideas where I'm going wrong ? Thanks in Advance

My codes:

**GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.Java**

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 573;

    private static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";

    /**
     * Convenience method for enqueuing work in to this service.
     */
    public static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent intent) {
        enqueueWork(context, GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handles incoming intents.
     * @param intent sent by Location Services. This Intent is provided to Location
     *               Services (inside a PendingIntent) when addGeofences() is called.
     */
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger multiple geofences.
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences);

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);

            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type, geofenceTransition));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets transition details and returns them as a formatted string.
     *
     * @param geofenceTransition    The ID of the geofence transition.
     * @param triggeringGeofences   The geofence(s) triggered.
     * @return                      The transition details formatted as String.
     */
    private String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
            int geofenceTransition,
            List<Geofence> triggeringGeofences) {

        String geofenceTransitionString = getTransitionString(geofenceTransition);

        // Get the Ids of each geofence that was triggered.
        ArrayList<String> triggeringGeofencesIdsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Geofence geofence : triggeringGeofences) {
            triggeringGeofencesIdsList.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        String triggeringGeofencesIdsString = TextUtils.join(", ",  triggeringGeofencesIdsList);

        return geofenceTransitionString + ": " + triggeringGeofencesIdsString;
    }

    /**
     * Posts a notification in the notification bar when a transition is detected.
     * If the user clicks the notification, control goes to the MainActivity.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Get an instance of the Notification manager
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
            // Create the channel for the notification
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts the main Activity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MapsActivity.class);

        // Construct a task stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        // Add the main Activity to the task stack as the parent.
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class);

        // Push the content Intent onto the stack.
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                // In a real app, you may want to use a library like Volley
                // to decode the Bitmap.
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.ic_launcher))
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setTicker(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.geofence_transition_notification_text))
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent);

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }

        // Dismiss notification once the user touches it.
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);

        // Issue the notification
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

    /**
     * Maps geofence transition types to their human-readable equivalents.
     *
     * @param transitionType    A transition type constant defined in Geofence
     * @return                  A String indicating the type of transition
     */
    private String getTransitionString(int transitionType) {
        switch (transitionType) {
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_entered);
            case Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT:
                return getString(R.string.geofence_transition_exited);
            default:
                return getString(R.string.unknown_geofence_transition);
        }
    }
}
```

**GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Enqueues a JobIntentService passing the context and intent as parameters
        GeofenceTransitionsJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
    }
}
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener, OnCompleteListener<Void>
{
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;


    static final int RADIUS = 500;

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    private Location location;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private Circle circle;
    private PendingIntent geofencePendingIntent;
    private GeofencingClient geofencingClient;

    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    private boolean isContinue = false;
    private boolean isGPS = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private final int UPDATE_INTERVAL =  2 * 60 * 1000;
    private final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 20 * 1000;
    private final int NOTIFICATION_RESPONSIVENESS_TIME = 10000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        createGoogleApi();

        new GpsUtils(this).turnGPSOn(new GpsUtils.onGpsListener() {
            @Override
            public void gpsStatus(boolean isGPSEnable) {
                // turn on GPS
                isGPS = isGPSEnable;
            }
        });

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        Log.d(TAG,"onMapReady()");
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this);
        addGeofence(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
        drawCircle(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
        markerForGeofence(getMyLocation());
    }

    private void createGoogleApi()
    {
        if(googleApiClient==null)
        {
            googleApiClient=new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        googleApiClient.connect();
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            //  removeGeofence();
            addGeofence(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
          //  drawCircle(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
        //    markerForGeofence(getMyLocation());
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

        super.onStop();
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected()");
        getLastKnownLocation();
        addGeofence(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
        drawCircle(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
        markerForGeofence(getMyLocation());
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionFailed()");
    }

    // Get last known location
    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation()");
        if ( checkPermissions() ) {
            location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if ( location != null ) {
                Log.i(TAG, "LasKnown location. " +
                        "Long: " + location.getLongitude() +
                        " | Lat: " + location.getLatitude());
                writeLocation();
                startLocationUpdates();
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "No location retrieved yet");
                startLocationUpdates();
            }
        }
        else requestPermissions();
    }

       // Start location Updates
    private void startLocationUpdates(){
        Log.i(TAG, "startLocationUpdates()");
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        if ( checkPermissions() )
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onLocationChanged ["+location+"]");
        location = location;
        writeActualLocation(location);
        addGeofence(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);
    }

    // Write location coordinates on UI
   private void writeActualLocation(Location location) {
        markerLocation(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    }

    private void writeLocation() {
        writeActualLocation(location);
    }

    private Marker locationMarker;
    // Create a Location Marker
    private void markerLocation(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerLocation("+latLng+")");
        String title = "Your Current Location("+latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude+")";
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title(title);
        if ( mMap!=null ) {
            // Remove the anterior marker
            if ( locationMarker != null )
                locationMarker.remove();
            locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            float zoom = 14f;
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
    }

    private Marker geoFenceMarker;
    // Create a marker for the geofence creation
    private void markerForGeofence(LatLng latLng) {
        Log.i(TAG, "markerForGeofence("+latLng+")");
        String title = "Your Geofence Area("+latLng.latitude + ", " + latLng.longitude+")";
        // Define marker options
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE))
                .title(title);
        if ( mMap!=null ) {
            // Remove last geoFenceMarker
            if (geoFenceMarker != null)
                geoFenceMarker.remove();

            geoFenceMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the current state of the permissions needed.
     */
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
        {
            return  false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        boolean shouldProvideRationale1 =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);


        // Provide an additional rationale to the user. This would happen if the user denied the
        // request previously, but didn't check the "Don't ask again" checkbox.
        if (shouldProvideRationale || shouldProvideRationale1) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");
            Snackbar.make(
                    findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                    R.string.permission_rationale,
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            // Request permission. It's possible this can be auto answered if device policy
            // sets the permission in a given state or the user denied the permission
            // previously and checked "Never ask again".
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }
    }


    // For creating GeoFence.
    private Geofence createGeofence(LatLng latLng, int radiusMeters) {
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
                // geofence.
                .setRequestId("1")
                .setCircularRegion(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude, radiusMeters)
                .setExpirationDuration(Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE)
                .setNotificationResponsiveness(NOTIFICATION_RESPONSIVENESS_TIME)
                .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER | Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                .build();
    }

    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest(LatLng latLng, int radiusMeters) {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_EXIT);
        builder.addGeofence(createGeofence(latLng, radiusMeters));
        return builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission was granted.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getLastKnownLocation();
                }
            } else {
                // Permission denied.
                // setButtonsState(false);
                Snackbar.make(
                        findViewById(R.id.activity_main),
                        R.string.permission_denied_explanation,
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(R.string.settings, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }).show();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
        // Return false so that we don't consume the event and the default behavior still occurs
        // (the camera animates to the user's current position).

       /* if (circle != null)
            circle.remove();
        drawCircle(getMyLocation(), RADIUS);*/

        return false;
    }

    private void drawCircle(LatLng latLng, int radius) {
        circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(latLng)
                .radius(radius)
                .strokeWidth(0f)
                .fillColor(0x55FF0000));
    }

    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        // Reuse the PendingIntent if we already have it.
        if (geofencePendingIntent != null) {
            return geofencePendingIntent;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceBroadcastReceiver.class);
        geofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

           return geofencePendingIntent;
    }

    private void removeGeofence() {
        geofencingClient.removeGeofences(getGeofencePendingIntent()).addOnCompleteListener(this);
    }

    private void addGeofence(LatLng latLng, int radiusMeters) {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(getGeofencingRequest(latLng, radiusMeters), getGeofencePendingIntent())
                .addOnCompleteListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   } else {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should re write your service as foreground otherwise it will get killer when user minimizes the app.

Answer (score 2):

Run Foreground service, when App goes to background. This solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, if an app is running in the background while monitoring a geofence, then the device responds to geofencing events every couple of minutes. To learn how to adapt your app to these response limits, see [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits).

You might need to run a sticky foreground service for your app to be running continuously.